# Чтение файла побайтово

Tags: c, файлы, указатели

Доброго времени суток. Имеется следующий код:

```
char *fileName = "1.jpg";
 FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
 char *buffer;

 if (fp != NULL) {
     if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_OUT) == 0) {
         buffer = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
         memset(buffer, 0, 10 * sizeof(char));
         if (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 10, fp) == 10) {
             // код ...
         }
     }
}
```

Проблема в том, что в блок, помеченный комментариями, программа не заходит. Идея программы -  считать первые 10 байт (именно байт). Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка или предложите принципиально другой выход (я новичок в си).

Comment: А зачем вам fseek, если вы читаете с начала? К тому же смущает константа SEEK_OUT. Обычно они называются SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END. Если SEEK_OUT случайно равно 2 (обычное значение для SEEK_END), то указатель файла встает на его конец, и тогда понятно, почему не читается.

Comment: Ой, верно, там `SEEK_SET`. Я не в курсе, почему я это написал (машинально, наверное.)

Comment: Ну, даже если SEEK_SET. Тогда вы устанавливаете указатель только что открытого файла на его начало (а он и так там стоит). То есть, этот вызов не нужен. А размер-то у файла какой? Там есть 10 байт? Что fread возвращает?

Comment: Хорошо, насчёт `fseek` учту. Размер 38 Кб, `freed` почему-то возвращает 0. По идее должен вернуть 10.

Comment: А у вас точно такой код? Гайка в гайку? Ибо вроде как должно работать...

Comment: Ага..Гайка в гайку..

Comment: Попробовал этот код у себя. Он ожидаемо выполнился. А что если сделать fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END), а затем запросить ftell(fp). Что она возвращает?

Comment: Вернула 0, как и ожидалось...(

Comment: Да нет, ожидалось, что она вернет те самые 38 К. Тогда выходит, что файл пустой. Вы точно тот файл открываете?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но он почему-то оказался пустым, хотя отображался постоянно как заполненный файл...Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Может вы его случайно затерли, например открыв по ошибке на запись. Бывает)